# tvOS sqlite linking error

Tags: sqlite, tvos

I am trying to re-use sqlite related code from my iOS application on tvOS and getting few linking errors as below

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_sqlite3_enable_load_extension", referenced from:
  "_sqlite3_load_extension", referenced from:

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am linking with libsqlite3.

The same code links fine on iOS. Seems like the library is missing some symbols for tvOS. Has anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: tvOS doesn't support local file system storage so not sure what you need SQLite for?

Comment: You can store data in NSCachesDirectory/ directory but it might get wiped out when the application is not running. I am thinking to use this temporary local storage to cache few things which can be re-fetched from the server if they don't exist but would save a trip to server if they

Comment: Have you tried writing files to cache directory on the actual device? While the simulator allows you to do this (necessary for debugging), an actual device will not. Save yourself the trouble and either use NSUserDefaults or use in-memory Core Data.